# How to handle incoming time-series data in a data warehouse?

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, datetime

I am new to data warehousing (having learnt this in my school days) and is looking to do a data warehouse as a side project. Below is a simple data warehouse design I came up with:
[image]

The data warehouse have 2 dimension tables and 1 fact table. 1 dimension table contains datetime data and the other contain the device data. The fact table contains the device incoming data values captured at the field. The data granularity in the fact table is 5 minutes.

I am confused on how time-series is being handled and will appreciate if someone can clarify this.  Assuming one row of data coming from the device looks like this:

```
    datetime        drive_a   drive_b   drive_c   shaft_a   shaft_b   shaft_c   total_output
02/01/2022 13:05      4.2       3.2       7.4       5.3       8.2       6.4        4563.2
```

This will be processed and stored into the fact table in the data warehouse.

How do I handle the `datetime` column from this incoming data since the `dateKey` is not the same format as the `datetime` incoming data?

I am thinking that the fact table need another column called `dateTime_raw`, but that defeat the purpose of a `dim_datetime` table isn't it since my datetime is already in my fact table?

P.S: Sorry if my question is confusing; trying my best to explain since I am not proficient in this field.

Comment: What are some example values of `dateKey`? Your `dim_datetime` table will essentially need a field that has the same granularity of dates and times as your `fact_deviceValues`  so you can relate the two together. By your example, it looks like that granularity is to the minute.

Comment: Hi J.D. I am thinking of putting incremental ID to `dateKey` to uniquely identify each row. I do not understand what you mean by same granularity of dates and times. Currently I do not have a field for this datetime in the fact table (this is one of the part I am confused if its needed). Am I right to say `dim_datetime` should not have seconds field? Should I keep the datetime data string as it is in the fact table (if so, how does this field works with `dim_datetime`, rather what is the purpose of `dim_datetime` in the first place?)? Appreciate if you have some examples. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your subsequent questions but basically, you example shows your fact table has a `datetime` field even though your picture doesn't show that? Your example also shows that `datetime` field has hours and minutes but not seconds. So your `dim_datetime` table should store `datetime`s with hours and minutes (doesn't need seconds) as a single field, to make joining easier.

Comment: Thanks J.D and sorry for the confusion. Indeed my example picture do not have the `datetime` field because I am confused at whether it needs to have (I figured now that this field is a must). In `dim_datetime`, I should have a `datetime` that is in the same format as the one in my fact table? Therefore the `dim_datetime` will have a FK `datetime` from fact table (all other fields remain the same as per example?)? Does it make sense to still have the hour, minutes in `dim_datetime`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you'll need a way to relate your timeseries fact data `fact_deviceValues` back to your datetime dimensions table `dim_datetime`. That should be by the `datetime` in both tables via a foreign key referencing from `fact_deviceValues` to `dim_datetime`.

The `datetime` should be the units of measure which you want to store your timeseries data for e.g. your example of `02/01/2022 13:05` has hours and minutes. That probably makes the `seconds` field unneeded in the `dim_datetime` table (unless you do plan to store data at the granularity of seconds).

Your parent `dim_datetime` table would have 1 row in it for every minute of every hour of every day, within a reasonable timeframe that covers your data and use cases. For example, if you needed to cover about 100 years worth of data, your `dim_datetime` table would have somewhere around 53 million rows (60 minutes * 24 hours * 365 days * 100 years = ~53 million) in it.

Whereas your child `fact_deviceValues` table would hold the actual `datetime` of the event that occurred in the timeseries. Multiple events could happen at the same `datetime` and therefor multiple rows would exist with the same value relating back to the same single parent row in the `dim_datetime` table.

If you find your `dim_datetime` table is too large, you may find a better architecture to make it a `dim_date` table instead that only stores 1 unique row per date. Then your `fact_deviceValues` table can store the date separately from the time, and can be joined to the `dim_date` table for the dimensions specific to dates (which are usually more abundant than dimensions specific to times). But this depends on your use cases, and if there are any dimensions specific to times you actually care about (any I can think of are usually derivable from the time itself anyway).